# OpenGL Assimp C++ Access Violation Reading Location 0x00000000

Tags: c++, opengl, access-violation, assimp

I have encountered a problem trying to run a simple model loader/displayer based off some tutorials. Whenever I compile the following code, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77ad15de in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

I know this means that a null pointer is being accessed which is illegal, but I cant seem to find one. Here is my code:

```cpp
gleMesh gleLoadMesh(const char* filename){
    const aiScene* scene = aiImportFile(filename, aiProcessPreset_TargetRealtime_Fast);

    if(!scene){
        fprintf(stderr,"[WARNING] Could not load file %s", filename);
        gleMesh load = {0,0,0,0};
        return load;
    }

    const struct aiMesh* mesh = scene->mMeshes[0];

    int tris = mesh->mNumFaces*3;
    float *verts = new float[mesh->mNumFaces*3*3];
    float *normals = new float[mesh->mNumFaces*3*3];
    float *uvs = new float[mesh->mNumFaces*3*3];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++){
        const aiFace face = mesh->mFaces[i];

        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            aiVector3D vert = mesh->mVertices[face.mIndices[j]];
            memcpy(verts, &vert, sizeof(float)*3);
            verts += 3;

            aiVector3D normal = mesh->mNormals[face.mIndices[j]];
            memcpy(normals, &normal, sizeof(float)*3);
            normals += 3;

            aiVector3D uv = mesh->mTextureCoords[0][face.mIndices[j]];
            memcpy(uvs, &uv, sizeof(float)*2);
            uvs += 2;
        }
    }

    gleMesh load = {0,0,0,0};

    if(glv3){
        glGenBuffers(1, &load.vertex);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, load.vertex);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verts), verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &load.normal);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, load.normal);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uvs), uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &load.uv);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, load.uv);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(uvs), uvs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        load.numTris = tris;
    }
    else{
        load.vertex = glGenLists(1);
        glNewList(load.vertex, GL_COMPILE);
        int j = 0;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->mNumFaces; i++){
                glNormal3f(normals[j], normals[j+1], normals[j+2]);
                glVertex3f(verts[j], verts[j+1], verts[j+2]);
                j+=3;
        }
        glEndList();
    }
    
    verts -= mesh->mNumFaces*3*3;
    normals -= mesh->mNumFaces*3*3;
    uvs -= mesh->mNumFaces*3*2;
    aiReleaseImport(scene);

    return load;
}
```

I use this function here:

```cpp
int main(){
    gleInit("Test", GLFW_WINDOW, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    mesh1 = gleLoadMesh("resource/model/test.blend");

    while(!glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)){
        draw();
        capFPS();
    }

    gleQuit();
    return 0;
}
```

The strangest part is, depending on what model format I choose to load, I will get an error break in a different place, but the error is always the same. I am using assimp version 3.0 and visual studio 2010.

Comment: Why not step debug through your code and see exactly where it crashes?

Comment: Oh right, sorry, forgot to add that. It crashes right when I initialize scene(line 2)

Comment: Have you managed to load anything successfully?

Comment: I tried a few different file types, but none worked.

Comment: You can also try Assimp::Importer and it's ReadFile method.

Comment: yes, I have tried that also with the same result.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: @user2415834: Why do you even think the crash is related to `assimp`. All you told as is that your code crashes somewhere in `gleLoadMesh`, which is not a very precise diagnose. There is a lot of GL code in there, and it could simply crash because you didn't properly initialize your GL loader.

Answer (score -1):

You are using a very old version of assimp. I strongly recommend to switch to the latest version or a newer one. If the crashes still occurs just add a new issue at the github page. I guess there is something broken in the used importer.